# Is there any technique to sort an array of 1D NumPy arrays containing floating values?

Tags: python, numpy

If I have an array of 1D NumPy arrays containing floating values is it possible to arrange that array into a manner where I can calculate Euclidean distance from a 1D array efficiently if the size of the array is too large?

**Sample Array**

```
[[-0.85,1.85,1,0.4,-1.2],
[-0.86,1.86,1.1,0.5,-1.3],
[-0.86,1.85,-1,0.4,-1.2],
[-0.85,1.85,-1,-0.4,-1.2],
[-0.85,-1.85,1,-0.4,-1.2],...]
```

`

**Array to calculate distance**  `[-0.12,0.76,1,-0.4,-1.46]`

**Distance formula I am using**  `dist = np.linalg.norm(point1 - point2)`

Is there any method where I can reduce the time to calculate the distance from every array in the large array as we do in general arrays with sorting and binary search as the linear search will go through the entire array?

I am already using multiprocessing but still, it takes time as the array is too large.

Comment: What's wrong with `np.linalg.norm(sample_array - point[None, :], axis=1)`?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me. You seems to assume that the data ordering of the computed array has an impact on the computation time. This is not true. `np.linalg.norm` will not be faster with sorted value so I did not understand the relation with sorting and a binary search unless you do some additional operations next that are not explicitly described here. Please clarify and describe more specifically the computation.

Comment: Just imagine if you have lots of points in a 3d plane and want to find out the nearest point from a given point, how to do that without traversing or calculating the distance from every point the all points? @JérômeRichard

Comment: Why would you do that? If you want to find the minimum distance of some point in a set of points A to some point B, you calculate all the distances from A to B and then find the lowest value.

Comment: Ok I got it, but this question is different from the problem stated in the question. Moreover, the question state 1D but the point appear to be in 5D... Please edit the question.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I will be thankful to you if you edit my question according to the problem as I am not able to explain my problem.

Comment: @Reti43 Finding the closest 5D point to another can be computed much more efficiently than computing the distance with all the other points and then take the minimal distance if the dataset is huge.

Comment: @GopalSinghSirvi You are the only one who can precisely describe the problem *you* have. I can just guess the problem as the others. Assuming you want to search for the closest point in a 5D space, this is a well-known problem (with many related questions/answers on SO) but not a simple one to solve. Please read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) for more information.

Comment: In `numpy` the fast compiled methods generally work with the whole-array.  Iterative search methods have to be written in Python, which is orders of magnitude slower.  So the brute force "search the whole array" approach is often faster, even though it uses more memory and has some higher "order" measure.  You have to use `numba` or `cython` or some other compiling approach to implement a custom fast searching algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you need to compute the euclidean distance for each one of the points in the "Sample Array" against the "Array to calculate distance". For this you can use the axis parameter in the norm function.

```
import numpy as np
s = np.array([[-0.85,1.85,1,0.4,-1.2],
        [-0.86,1.86,1.1,0.5,-1.3],
        [-0.86,1.85,-1,0.4,-1.2],
        [-0.85,1.85,-1,-0.4,-1.2]])
p = np.array([-0.12,0.76,1,-0.4,-1.46])
distance = np.linalg.norm(s-p, axis=1))
print(distance)
```

According to the comments, you should check for a kdtree. There are implementations in [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html) and  [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html)

Comment: but it will loop through the whole array, right? I just want to minimize time complexity. Just wanted to find out if there is any technique to rearrange the sample array in a manner so that we will not need to loop the whole array.

Comment: Edited, check for kdtrees

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can try array broadcasting to calculate the Euclidean distance.

```
import numpy as np

#created a random array
arr1 = np.random.rand(4000000, 50)    
print(arr1.shape)

arr2 = np.random.rand(50)
print(arr2.shape)

import time
t1 = time.time()
ecludian_distance = np.sqrt(np.sum((arr1-arr2)**2, axis = 1))
print(ecludian_distance)
print(time.time()-t1, 'seconds')
```

[image: code running on google colab]

It is taking less than a second to compute.

You can further increase by dropping the `np.sqrt()` function if you are only concerned about the order of distances.